# Would you be able to add an NBT tag to an already 'spawned' mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

After a mob is spawned, or summoned, would it be possible to give it more NBT tags? For example, could I have something such as `/nbt @e NoAI:1` (I know that's not a real command) to freeze every mob in the game? Or `/nbt @e[type=villager] Invisible:1` to give all villagers the 'Invisible' NBT tag?

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/data

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be done with the /data command. The format is

> "/data get/merge/modify/remove block/entity (selector) {nbt}".

What you'd want is

> "/data merge entity (selector) {nbt}".

Here's an example for you:

> "/data merge entity @e[type=villager,limit=1] {Invulnerable:1b}"

The data command only works on one entity at a time, so all selectors must have a "limit=1" in it- but no fear, there's a way around it. We just make the entities execute the command to themselves.

> "/execute as (selector) run data merge entity @s {nbt}".

Example:

> "/execute as @e[type=villager] run data merge entity @s {Invulnerable:1b}"

This would make **ALL** villagers invulnerable.